# change window location

Tags: javascript

My code opens a new window with the name `radio` I am curious to know how I can change the url for this window automatically every hour from `radio.php` to `/server2/radio.php`

```
<a href="#" onclick="RadioLink('radio.php','radio','width=300,height=150')">Play Radio</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function RadioLink(theURL,winName,features) {
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean? change it on open windows?

Comment: @leon the url for the window that opens

Comment: @FAFAFOHI - Also, are you trying to manage your traffic? Can you do that on the server side (assuming this is what you're trying to do)?

Comment: @FAFAFOHI that's javascript, so it means it's written on some HTML/XHTML/whatever markup that is by itself not dynamic. You have one url - what do you mean by _every_ _hour_? you have one, changed it once after one hour, will you change it again to same thing it's been changed to after one hour?

Comment: @leon - A `setInterval()`, while perhaps not the best option, would make what FAFAFOHI seems to be suggesting possible, with the construction of `theURL` based on some algorithm.

Comment: @Jared - true, but still, we have one source and then one target. I also agree with you in regards to the OP being load balancing - but passing that onto the client-side does not sound like such a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var mywnd;
function RadioLink(theURL,winName,features) {
  mywnd = window.open(theURL,winName,features);
  setInterval('mywnd.location.href = "/server2/radio.php";', 3600000);
}
//-->
</script>
```

This will change the URL after one hour.

Comment: @Saar - `setInterval()` could change it "every hour". ;)

Comment: @Saar - I don't know. Read the question, it's what FAFAFOHI is looking for.

Comment: @Saar - Also, I believe the url may not point at the same one each time; there may be 2, 5 or 10 servers. My guess is he is load balancing.

Comment: @FAFAFOHI Can't see one. Maybe mywnd.location.href should be mywnd.location.